# Clojure - how macroexpansion works inside of the "some" function

Tags: clojure, macros, lisp

Just when I thought I had a pretty good handle on macros, I came across the source for `some` which looked a bit odd to me at first glance.

```
(defn some
  [pred coll]
    (when (seq coll)
      (or (pred (first coll)) (recur pred (next coll)))))
```

My first instinct was that seems like it would be stack consuming, but then I remembered: "No, dummy, `or` is a macro so it would simply expand into a ton of nested `ifs`".

However mulling it over a bit more I ended up thinking myself in a corner. At expansion time the function source would look like this:

```
(defn some
  [pred coll]
    (when (seq coll)
      (let [or__4469__auto__  (pred (first coll))]
         (if or__4469__auto__ 
             or__4469__auto__ 
             (recur pred (next coll))))))
```

Now what's got me confused is that final `recur` call. I've always thought that macroexpansion occurs prior to runtime, yet here you have to actually call the already expanded code at runtime in order for the second macroexp .... wait a second, I think i just figured it out.

There is no second macroexpansion, there are no nested `if` blocks, only the one `if` block.  The call to `recur` just keeps rebinding `pred` and `coll` but the same single block above keeps testing for truth until it finds it, or the collection runs out and `nil` is returned.

Can someone confirm if this is a correct interpretation? I had initially confused myself thinking that there would be an interleaving of macroexpansion and runtime wherein at runtime the call to recur would somehow result in a new macro call, which didn't make sense since macroexpansion must occur prior to runtime. Now I think I see where my confusion was, there is only ever one macro expansion and the resulting code is used over and over in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, note that any function can serve as an implicit `loop` expression.  Also, `recur` works just like a recursive function call, except it does not use up the stack because of a compiler trick (that is why `loop` & `recur` are "special forms" - they don't follow the rules of normal functions).

Also, remember that `when` is a macro that expands into an `if` expression.

Having said all that, you did reach the correct conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are two modes of recursion going on here:

- The `or` *macro* is implicitly recursive, provoked by the sequence of argument
  forms into generating a tree of `if` forms.
- The `some` *function* is explicitly recursive, provoked into telling the single
  sequence of its final argument. The fact that this recursion is
  `recur`able is irrelevant.

Every argument to the `or` macro beyond the first generates a nested `if` form. For example, ...

```
=> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(or a b c)) 
(let* [or__5501__auto__ a]
  (if or__5501__auto__ or__5501__auto__
    (let* [or__5501__auto__ b]
      (if or__5501__auto__ or__5501__auto__ c))))
```

You have two arguments to `or`, so one `if` form. As [Alan Thompson's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56763746/1562315) points out, the surrounding `when` unwraps into another `if` form.

You can have as many nested `if` forms as you like, the leaves of the `if` tree, all of them, are in tail position. Hence all immediate recursive calls there are `recur`able. If there was no such tail recursion, the `recur` call would fail to compile.